# Find the volume of the solid bounded by the surfaces $x = 1 − y^{2}$ , $x = −1$ and $z^{2} = 1 − x$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solid bounded by the surfaces

$x = 1 − y^{2}$ , $x = −1$ and $z^{2} = 1 − x$

I am having a bit of difficulty setting up the bounds for this question.

So far I have got:

- $-1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1-y^{2}$
- $-\sqrt{2} \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{2}$
- $-\sqrt{2} \leqslant z \leqslant \sqrt{2}$

Can someone please confirm if I am on the right track?

Comment: Big hint: consider that $x=1-y^{2}$, $x=-1$, and $x=1-z^{2}$; draw an *xyz* system and graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ V=\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} \int_{-1}^{1-y^2} \int_{-\sqrt {1-x}}^{\sqrt {1-x}} dz \;dx\;dy $$